# Julia Pipeline with multiple argument

Tags: julia

Let's say, we have couple of functions named as `f!(x,y,z)`, `g!(x,y,z)` and `h!(x,y,z)`. Each function takes the input arguments, do some operation and returns nothing but make changes on input arguments.
For instance;

```
function f!(x,y,z)
   x = x+1
   y = y+2
   z = z+3
   return nothing
end
```

For the sake of simplicity, we can assume `g!` and `h!` function does similar operations, and return nothing.

My question is How can we create a pipeline in Julia to call these 3 functions in order? I tried the code below. But it didn't work. How can we make it work?

```
@pipe (x,y,z) |> f! |> g! |> h!
```

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: The `f!` in the example isn't so great, as it doesn't feel like it is mutating the inputs. Perhaps `x[1] += 1` and such would be better example statements.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use three separate lines for this? `f!(x,y,z); g!(x,y,z); h!(x,y,z)` seems like a pretty clear and common way do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the functions return nothing. Piping is applying a function to the previous function's output : `(x,y,z)` should be returned in order to be piped to the next function, otherwise it doesn't really make sense to use a pipeline at all.

The other issue is that `x,y,z` are immutable, so you would have to either

- Reassign them a value explicitly :

  ```jl
  # Assuming g and h do similar operations and return (x,y,z)

  function f(x,y,z)
      x = x+1
      y = y+2
      z = z+3
      return (x,y,z)
  end

  x,y,z = 0,0,0

  x,y,z = @pipe (x,y,z) |> f(_...) |> g(_...) |> h(_...)
  ```
- Define a `mutable struct` with fields x, y, and z and use it instead of just `(x,y,z)` :

  ```
  mutable struct Point{T<:Real}
      x::T
      y::T
      z::T
  end
  ```

  ```jl
  # Assuming g! and h! do similar operations and return p

  function f!(p::Point)
      p.x += 1
      p.y += 2
      p.z += 3
      return p
  end

  p = Point(0, 0, 0)

  @pipe p |> f! |> g! | h!
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Your first proposition solves my problem. In fact, I have multiple mutable structs as inputs for each function f!, g!, h!.

Answer (score 0):

How is this as a solution:

```
x = []; y = []; z = []
f!(x,y,z) = (push!(x,1); push!(y,2); push!(z,3); nothing )
g!(x,y,z) = (push!(x,4); push!(y,5); push!(z,6); nothing )
h!(x,y,z) = (push!(x,7); push!(y,8); push!(z,9); nothing )

foreach(f -> f(x,y,z), (f!, g!, h!))
```

Comment: Looks overcomplicated :-) :-) :-)